# Boost::Signals for C++ Data copying

Tags: c++, visual-studio, events, boost, boost-signals

Recently I had a class that looked like

```
class IGraphElement{
    typedef void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;
public:
    void Add(FuncCharPtr* f)
    {
        FuncVec.push_back(f);
    }
    void CastData(char * data, int length){
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < FuncVec.size(); i++){
            char* dataCopy = new char[length];
            memcpy(dataCopy, data, length);
            FuncVec[i](dataCopy, length);
        }
    }
private:
    vector<FuncCharPtr*> FuncVec ;
};
```

There I was giving to all subscribers a pointer to there copy of data. Now I want to make my class to use boost. I understand that with boost I will be free from typedef  and vector instead I would have something like

```
class IGraphElement{

public:
  signal<void (char*, int) > SigB;
```

but how shall be CastData rewritten for me to keep controll over data which will be sent/casted to subscribers?

Comment: I want to keep as much managament of data copiing as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing one mistake: you assume that the function you're calling will free the resources (the char* pointer) you give it. You should do something like:

```
void CastData(char * data, int length){
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < FuncVec.size(); i++){
        char* dataCopy = new char[length];
        memcpy(dataCopy, data, length);
        FuncVec[i](dataCopy, length);
        delete[] dataCopy;
    }
}
```

Now, about the boost::signals. The signal simply holds a list of function pointers. If the signal is raised, it just calls each function in that list with the specified parameters. Something like:

```
class signal { //non-templated version
public:
    void operator() (Params) 
    {
        for (FuncList::iterator i = f_.begin(); i != f_.end(); ++i) {
            (**i)(Params);
        }
    }
private:
    typedef ... Function;
    typedef std::vector<Function> FuncList;
    FuncList f_;
}
```

Since the parameters are passed directly, you will have to encapsulate your data structure into a helper class. You will do the memory management in the copy constructor.

Comment: my exact point is not to free resources!) One graph element passes to all subscribers  copy (in future I hope to pass  also original pointer it currently has) of its currently generated data. And they (if they do not pass that pointer further) will be cleaning up.

Comment: and how to  encapsulate data structure into a helper class - please provide example?

Comment: @jons34yp "Now, about the boost::signals. The signal simply holds a list of function pointers."   I need to disagree. Signal holds a list of functors (that's why you can use a boost::bind with it), which is a much broader entity.

Comment: @Marcin. Yes, I agree, but for illustrative purposes clearness has higher priority than factual accuracy

Comment: @Kabumbus: Oh, OK. Unfortunately this doesn't make things easier :) But why not to pass a const reference (or pointer) to the data? In that way the subscribers would make copies only as needed. The compiler would still protect the data against any inadvertent changes to the data.

Comment: generally solution to my problem appeared here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845504/how-to-make-typedef-on-void-function-that-could-be-property-of-any-class/4845529#4845529