# How to make typedef on void function that could be property of any class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, vector, typedef

When we do

```
typedef void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;
vector<FuncCharPtr*> FuncVec ;
void Add(FuncCharPtr* f)
{
    FuncVec.push_back(f);
}
```

we do not allow to pass as FuncCharPtr types like

```
 void (someClass::*)b(char*, int);
 void (someOtherClass::*)b(char*, int);
```

and we want to keep links to functions from both classes in same vector so to be able to call all subscribers at once WITH SOMETHING LIKE

```
void CastData(char * data, int length){
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < FuncVec.size(); i++){
        char* dataCopy = new char[length];
        memcpy(dataCopy, data, length);
        FuncVec[i](dataCopy, length);
                    delete[] dataCopy;
    }
}
```

How to solve such problemm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a function pointer for this.  The class type is a part of the type of a pointer to a member function, so there is no one type that would work.

The best way to accomplish what you want to do is to use [the `function` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function.html) and [the `bind` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html) from Boost, C++ TR1, or C++0x.

You can maintain a `std::vector<std::function<void(char*, int)> >` and use the `bind` function to bind pointers to member functions to the instance of the class on which you want the member function to be called:

```
struct A { void foo(int) { } };
struct B { void bar(int) { } };

typedef std::function<void(int)>   Function;
typedef std::vector<Function>      FunctionSequence;
typedef FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator;

FunctionSequence funcs;

A a;
B b;

funcs.push_back(std::bind(&A::foo, &a, std::placeholders::_1));
funcs.push_back(std::bind(&B::bar, &b, std::placeholders::_1));

// this calls a.foo(42) then b.bar(42):
for (FunctionIterator it(funcs.begin()); it != funcs.end(); ++it)
    (*it)(42);
```

Comment: Could you provide any links or code samples on how to implement std::vector<std::function<void(char*, int)> > solution? It would be really grate!

Comment: @Kabumbus:  It would look something like what I've shown in the example here.  Your argument types would differ depending on the actual types of the functions.

Comment: I loved your class... and somehow updated it... and got error described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853263/why-so-many-errors-here-in-typedef

Comment: (for future readers) and another discussion on this method and boost::bind can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853542/boost-std-bind-how-to-solve-such-errors-binding-function-from-one-class-to-anot