# Why so many errors here in typedef?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, boost

from this:

```
   // parts of c++0x std
    #include <boost/bind.hpp> 
    #include <boost/function.hpp>

    #ifndef _IGraphElement_h_
    #define _IGraphElement_h_

    using namespace std ;
    template <typename DataType >
    class IGraphElement : public IGraphElementBase{

        typedef boost::function<void(DataType)>   Function;
        typedef std::vector<Function>      FunctionSequence;  // (line *)
        typedef FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator; // (line **)
//...
};
```

I get C2146 and C4430 on line ** at the same time!( How to fix such thing?

Comment: When you get errors with templates and `typedef`, there's an 85% chance that you forgot a `typename`. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typedef FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator; // (line **)
```

This should be written as,

```
typedef typename FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator;
```

Since `iterator` is a dependent name, so `typename` is required!

Read about dependent name here:

- [Name binding and dependent names (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/name_binding.htm)
- [Dependent Names](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/427) (scroll down and read this section - better if you read the complete article)

Answer (score 1):

- You need a `typename` as mentioned by others ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs) for more details).
- You forgot `;` in `InitGet` method after `dataElement = DataElement`.
- You miss some headers, `GraphItemMutex`, `GraphItemMutexConditionVariable` and `GraphWorker` objects.