# Boost/std bind how to solve such errors? (binding function from one class to another class)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, boost

So I am triing to create a simple graph connecting one class to another...

```
#include "IGraphElement.h"

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class  simpleRendererGraphElement : public IGraphElementBase, public simpleRendererLibAPI
{
public:
    IGraphElement<ExtendedCharPtr>* charGenerator;
    // we owerrite init
    void Init(IGraphElement<ExtendedCharPtr>* CharGenerator, int sleepTime)
    {
        charGenerator = CharGenerator;
        charGenerator->Add(boost::bind(&simpleRendererGraphElement::renderCastedData, this, std::placeholders::_1)); // line (**)

        SetSleepTime(sleepTime);
    }
    void renderCastedData(ExtendedCharPtr data) //  our event system receives functions declared like void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;
    { 
        DWCTU();
        renderChar(data.data);
    }

};
```

But it gives me C3083 and C2039 on line (**)... I use vs 2008 so I can not se std to bind... how to solve such issue?

BTW `#include "IGraphElement.h"` looks like

```
#include "IGraphElementBase.h"

// parts of c++0x std
#include <boost/bind.hpp> 
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#ifndef _IGraphElement_h_
#define _IGraphElement_h_

using namespace std ;
template <typename DataType >
class IGraphElement : public IGraphElementBase{

    typedef boost::function<void(DataType)>   Function;
    typedef std::vector<Function>      FunctionSequence;
    typedef typename FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator; 

private:
    DataType dataElement;
    FunctionSequence funcs;

public:

    void InitGet(DataType DataElement)
    {
        dataElement = DataElement;
    }

    // Function for adding subscribers functions
    // use something like std::bind(&currentClassName::FunctionToAdd, this, std::placeholders::_1) to add function to vector
    void Add(Function f)
    {
        funcs.push_back(f);
    }

};
#endif // _IGraphElement_h_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `boost::bind` you need to use `boost::placeholders`.  You can't mix-and-match.

(Visual C++ 2008 doesn't even include `std::placeholders`, though; the TR1 service pack includes `std::tr1::placeholders`, but the C++0x `std::placeholders` wasn't introduced until Visual C++ 2010.)

Comment: and how to solve such situation in VS08 - is there any way to get rid of that placeholders?

Comment: but I do not see headers in boost for  boost::placeholders only for  boost::is_placeholder=( where to get boost with  placeholders for VS08?

Comment: Apparently they have been moved into an unnamed namespace and can be referred to simply as `_1`, `_2`, etc.  See [the documentation for details](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html).