# Boost Connect Signal From one class to another

Tags: c++, boost

I need to emit a signal from child class to it's parent class when an asynchronous operation finished using boost signal,

For example my parent class

```
class A
{
    void doTask(){
      class B child;
      child.asynchTask();
    }

    void onFinished(){
      //invoke it when async task finished
    }
};
```

And the second class

```
class B
{
     void asynchTask(){
     //Async task start  here 

    }

 void asynchTaskFinished(){
      // Emit signal from here to invoke onFinished() of parent class

    }

};
```

How can I do it using boost signal, I already found some  example and an SO post  [Complete example using Boost::Signals for C++ Eventing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768351/complete-example-using-boostsignals-for-c-eventing), but couldn't figure out how to implement in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Haris

Comment: What is so special about this case? Define a signal in `class B`, and connect it with a slot bound to the instance of `class A`. By the way, if it's just a kind of completion handler, `asynchTask` can just accept an `std::function`, and invoke it on completion. Signals are more appropriate for multiple slots/notifications.